# How to escape square brackets in expect?

Tags: bash, tcl, expect

I am not able to escape square braces in the expect script, the example as below,

I have a question.sh script as below,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? [Y/n]"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 50 and do cleanup? [Y/n]"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 51 and do cleanup? [Y/n]"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 52 and do cleanup? [Y/n]"
read $REPLY
```

For the above question.sh I have the below answer.exp, and execute the same with **'expect answer.exp 51'** command,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ./question.sh

set item "Deleted Item with ID: "
append item [lindex $argv 0]
append item " and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]"

expect "Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? \[Y/n\]"
send -- "Y\r"

expect {

      $item {
            send "Y\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      " and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]" {
            send "n\r"
            exp_continue
      }
}
```

When ever I have the square braces involved the expect is not matching and does not send the answer (Y/N) back.

The same when I remove the square braces from the question and the answer scripts expect works fine, the changed question and answer scripts as below.

**question.sh:**

```
 #!/bin/bash
echo "Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? Y/n"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 50 and do cleanup? Y/n"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 51 and do cleanup? Y/n"
read $REPLY

echo "Deleted Item with ID: 52 and do cleanup? Y/n"
read $REPLY
```

**answer.exp:**

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ./question.sh

set item "Deleted Item with ID: "
append item [lindex $argv 0]
append item " and do cleanup? Y/n"

expect "Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? Y/n"
send -- "Y\r"

expect {

      $item {
            send "Y\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      " and do cleanup? Y/n" {
            send "n\r"
            exp_continue
      }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at my [sexpect (Expect for Shells)](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect) which you can use to write Expect scripts with **shell code only**.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `expect` command matches against tcl [`string match` style wildcard patterns](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/string.htm#M35) by default, so `[Y/n]` is trying to match one of the characters Y, forward slash or n.

Solutions:

1. Add more backslashes:

```
append item " and do cleanup? \\\[Y/n\\\]"
```

so it turns into `\[Y/N\]`.

2. Use braces instead:

```
append item { and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]}
```

to prevent the substitution of backslashes.

3. Tell `expect` to do an exact match by using the `-ex` option before each pattern:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ./question.sh

set item "Deleted Item with ID: "
append item [lindex $argv 0]
append item " and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]"

expect -ex "Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? \[Y/n\]"
send -- "Y\r"

expect {

      -ex $item {
            send "Y\r"
            exp_continue
      }
      -ex " and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]" {
            send "n\r"
            exp_continue
      }
}
```

Comment: You can also combine 2 and 3: `expect -ex {Would you like to specify inputs and execute the script? [Y/n]}`

Comment: BTW: AFIK you only need to escape the opening bracket, not the closing one.

Comment: @user1934428 Wouldn't surprise me, but it looks weird that way.

Comment: This is because a single closing bracket does not make sense anyway. It's the same in i.e. bash, where you can do an `echo ]` without caring of interpretation of wildcard characters.

Comment: An even better solution would be IMO to use `{....}` as string terminator instead of `" .... "`, since we don't do interpolation anyway. With this, you don't nee to escape anything.

Comment: @user1934428 That's one of the options I gave, yes.

Comment: Setting `item` could be done easier in a single statement, this time of course **with** interpolation and hence the need to escape: `set item "Deleted Item with ID: [lindex $argv 0] and do cleanup? \[Y/n\]"`

Comment: Ah, right. Missed that line. I would recommend using this style consistently in your solution (3) too, i.e. write `-ex { and do cleanup? [Y/n]}`, because solutions 2 and 3 don't exclude each other.